# Remove duplicates and finding unique sublists

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[4,5],[2,3],[2,4],[4,2]]
```

I would like to find the unique sublists in `lst`. Using the above example, I'd like to find:

```
lst_set = [1,2,3],[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[2,4]]
```

Order does not matter. In otherwords, `[2,4]` and `[4,2]` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [22]: lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[4,5],[2,3],[2,4],[4,2]]

In [23]: set(frozenset(item) for item in lst)
Out[23]: 
set([frozenset([2, 4]),
     frozenset([1, 2]),
     frozenset([2, 3]),
     frozenset([1, 2, 3]),
     frozenset([4, 5])])
```

Comment: nice, didn't know about frozenset

Comment: oh wow, thanks. i also didn't know about the frozenset.

Comment: It has problem when the sublists have repeated elements e.g. [1,2,3, 3], [1,1,2,3]

Answer (score 4):

```
set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the built-in `set()` function. As the list is unhashable, you might need to turn the lists into a tuple before using set().

That means:

```
set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in lst])
```